# Restrict usage in header and source

Tags: c++, restrict

Do we need to use the restrict keyword in both declaration and definition of methods or is it enough to use it only in declaration files in c++ code? What is the right way to use it?

Code compiles even without **restrict** usage in declaration.

For example

```
Foo.h
class Foo
{
    public:
    void Bar(int* __restrict__ in, int* __restrict__ out);
}


Foo.cpp

void Foo::Bar(int* __restrict__ in, int* __restrict__ out)
{
}
```

Comment: [**"As with all outermost parameter qualifiers, `__restrict__` is ignored in function definition matching. This means you only need to specify `__restrict__` in a function definition, rather than in a function prototype as well."**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting answer from @StoryTeller

```
    As with all outermost parameter qualifiers, __restrict__ is ignored in 
function definition matching. This means you only need to specify __restrict__ in 
a function definition, rather than in a function prototype as well." – StoryTeller 
May 8 at 10:25
```